# Issues with App since Facebook removed app profile pages - how to add my app 

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

I built an application for Facebook a couple of months ago.  I used the iframe method which allows people to add my App to a facebook page as a tab. Information on this below:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

I have tested this in various different accounts and it all seems to be working great apart from one persons account.  The difference between this account and all the others is that she is using a facebook page instead of a profile.  Therefore there is no "Add to my Page" link in the left hand navigation when the user is on my application page.

After reading the instructions above again, I noticed the instructions have changed since I first made the app and now adding an App to a Page has to be done different.  Its is stating I need to include a link.  However, where do I add this link?  To my canvas page?  If this is the case, my users do not go direct to my canvas page until they have added the tab.

I have also come accross the below changes Facebook have made which has obviously connected with the problems I am having.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

I am totally confused as to what I need to do,can anyone help?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods are:

- Use the API directly once the user has authorised your app and you have an `access_token` for their page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page#tabs
- Use the 'add to page' dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

A simple example for the add to page dialog is just to send the user to  `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL` (must be a URL listed in your app settings)

The old endpoint that the 'Add to my page' link used to go to should also still work but i'm not sure of the URL format for that one

Comment: Yes I understand I need to add the "add to page page dialog" link, but where do I add this?  To my canvas page?  It is not clear in  the instructions.  And also what do I put as YOUR_URL?  The link to my application?   Many thanks

Comment: Well, wherever users are going to find your app seems like a good place to put the link - on your app page's wall, your website, etc?
And yes, the 'next' parameter is where the user is brought to after adding the tab; the link needs to be derived from your app's canvas or website URL; most developers bring the user to a 'thanks, here's how to configure your new tab' type page

Answer (score -1):

To add an app to your Facebook Page, first go to the App profile Page. On the left hand side of the app profile page you can see the "Add to My Page" link.

For more info please check http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=172925542764476

Comment: The "Add to My Page" link is not there in this persons case.  It is there for everyone else who has a profile and then creates a page, but it is not there for the person who has page and not a profile.

Comment: All app profile pages were deprecated as of Feb 1st and regular pages don't have that link

Comment: If this has been deprecated, then why does the "Add to my page" link still exist in some peoples case?  Poeple who have a facebook profile.  Thsi is causing me the confusion.

Comment: Some App profile pages may still be visible if they haven't yet been removed, but the 'add to my page' link won't be on any pages in the near future